# Enabling Mock Locations in ChromeOS

Tags: chromebook, google-chrome-os, gps

I'm looking for a way to use external bluetooth GPS receiver with a Chromebook (because my Chromebook, like many others doesn't have build in GPS).

My Chrome OS version is 79.0.3940.0 (Build officiel) dev (64 bits)).

Is there a simple way to do this?